# The asymptotic behavior of solutions of a linear system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Find the 3 real solutions to the following system of ODEs and describe the behaviour as $t$ approached infinity.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x   \\
    y  \\
    z 
\end{bmatrix}'=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & -1  \\
    -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    x   \\
    y  \\
    z 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I solved the system of differential equations and I got this.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x   \\
    y  \\
    z 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 & 1  \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    e^t & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & \cos(t) & \sin(t) \\
    0 & -\sin(t) & \cos(t) 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    c_1 \\
    c_2  \\
    c_3 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know that because of the complex conjugate eigenvalue pair it creates some kind of circular winding motion. Does it spiral out into the x direction?

Comment: Every linear system X'=AX starting at the point X=0 stays there hence the part where you ask that the system starts at X=0 is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

You obtained :
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x   \\
    y  \\
    z 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 & 1  \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    e^t & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & cos(t) & sin(t) \\
    0 & -sin(t) & cos(t) 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    c_1 \\
    c_2  \\
    c_3 
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
    -c_2\cos(t)-c_2\sin(t) +c_3\cos(t)-c_3\sin(t)  \\
    c_1e^t-c_2\sin(t)+c_3\cos(t)  \\
    c_1e^t-c_2\cos(t)-c_3\sin(t) 
\end{bmatrix}$$
It seems that this result doesn't satisfy the DE : Bringing it back into the DE shows discrepancies.

Moreover, the starting vector seems to leads to a strange result : Puting $t=0$ into your solution leads to : 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    -c_2 +c_3  \\
    c_1+c_3  \\
    c_1-c_2 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
    0  \\
    0 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$c_1=c_2=c_3=0$$

My own result is :
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x   \\
    y  \\
    z 
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
    -C_2\cos(t)+C_2\sin(t) -C_3\cos(t)-C_3\sin(t)  \\
    C_1e^t+C_2\sin(t)-C_3\cos(t)  \\
    C_1e^t-C_2\cos(t)-C_3\sin(t) 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Again, more convenient starting conditions have to be defined.

Comment: One knows without computations that every linear system X'=AX starting at the point X=0 stays there hence there is no need to do all this to see that the initial condition X(0)=0 is absurd.

Comment: Hi Did ! The aim is not to discuss the initial condition, but to compare the solution found by Panphobia to my own solution. It is of interest to point out a probable mistake. Doing all this was just for that.

Comment: Actually, with the correct constants of integration c_1=c_2=c_3=0 the solution by the OP also solves the system since it reduces to X(t)=0... More seriously, it is much more important to point to the OP their misconception about linear systems magically evading from their equilibrium point than their mostly irrelevant computational mistakes.

Comment: @Did That was the exact problem given by my professor, including the vector \begin{bmatrix}
    0   \\
    0  \\
    0 
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: @Panphobia Hmmm... Which is why you "took away [this piece of] wrong info"?

Comment: Well if it's wrong, it's wrong...Doesn't matter who gave me the problem. I am sorry for offending you with my stupidity, but I genuinely posted this for help. Anyway, maybe he meant what the solution looked like around X = 0. Would that still be absurd?